# VBA Inconsistent Run-time error '91'

Tags: vba, excel

Just as a foreword, I'm not much of a programmer. Just trying to band-aid a macro for a one off use.

Currently need to cycle through ~3700 lines in excel and find certain words in around ~100 word documents.

Basically line 1 needs to find the word "donkey" (cell A1) and searches the document listed in cell A4, then produces how many times the word was found and if greater than 2 times, marks the cell "YES".

My problem is, sometimes it will run to completion, sometimes when opening the next document I receive the error

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Usually restarting excel or changing the file path of the documents being search fixes it for one or two runs. This makes me believe it has something to do with memory, but I'm unsure.

Any ideas what the issue is? Thanks!

Here's the code as-is, yes it's sloppy.

```
Sub FindName()
    Dim wrdApp As Object
    Dim wrdDoc As Object
    Dim maxRowCount As Integer
    Dim TP As String
    Dim FindWord As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iCount As Integer

    TP = "003"

        i = 115
        maxRowCount = 140

     On Error Resume Next
            Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
            If Err.Number > 0 Then Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            On Error GoTo 0
            wrdApp.Visible = True

    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\TP\X-" & TP & ".docx")

    For i = i To maxRowCount



      If Cells(i, 4).Text = TP Then

         FindWord = Cells(i, 1).Text

         '// Defines selection for Word's find function
         wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst
         wrdDoc.SelectAllEditableRanges
         iCount = 0

         '// Word Find Method Setup Block
         With wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
             .Text = FindWord
             .Replacement.Text = ""
             .Forward = True
             .Wrap = 1 ' wdFindContinue (Word constant not defined in Excel)
             .Format = False
             .MatchCase = True
             .MatchWholeWord = True
             .MatchWildcards = False
             .MatchSoundsLike = False
             .MatchAllWordForms = False
            Do While wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute
                iCount = iCount + 1
                wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveRight
               ' MsgBox iCount
            Loop
         End With


         '// Unnecessary storing, I know
         result = iCount
         Cells(i, 6).Value = result
         If result > 1 Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "YES"
         Else
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "NO"
         End If



      Else

      TP = Cells(i, 4).Text
      FindWord = Cells(i, 1).Value
        '// Close and don't save application
        wrdApp.Quit SaveChanges:=0 ' wdDoNotSaveChanges (Word constant not defined in Excel)

        Set wrdApp = Nothing
        Set wrdDoc = Nothing

            On Error Resume Next
            Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
            If Err.Number > 0 Then Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            On Error GoTo 0


        Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\TP\X-" & TP & ".docx")



        '// Defines selection for Word's find function

         wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst
         wrdDoc.SelectAllEditableRanges
         iCount = 0
         '// Word Find Method Setup Block
         With wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
             .Text = FindWord
             .Replacement.Text = ""
             .Forward = True
             .Wrap = 1 ' wdFindContinue (Word constant not defined in Excel)
             .Format = False
             .MatchCase = True
             .MatchWholeWord = True
             .MatchWildcards = False
             .MatchSoundsLike = False
             .MatchAllWordForms = False
            Do While wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute
                iCount = iCount + 1
                wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.MoveRight
            Loop
         End With


         '// Unnecessary storing, I know
         result = iCount
         Cells(i, 6).Value = result
         If result > 1 Then
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "YES"
         Else
                Cells(i, 7).Value = "NO"
         End If
      End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: What line is your error occurring?

Comment: Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\TP\X-" & TP & ".docx")

in the Else section. I've had it print out what document it's opening and directory/document name is perfect.

Comment: You syntax is ok. Try to insert before the faulty line: `debug.print "C:\TP\X-" & TP & ".docx"` and look at the result using `ctrl+G`

Comment: @PatrickHonorez The document path and name are correct when checking the debug.

Comment: @BenWest then try to manually open Word before running again with all `on error` removed ?

Comment: @PatrickHonorez This fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: you are not closing the word document

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax on the error line seems correct. You can:
- verify the filename by insrting a `debug.print` line to show the filename expression
- verify the Word instanciation by opening Word manually, removing the `On error` in your code, and running it again.